# Solving the 1-D Heat equation of a rod completely breaks down after 8 iterations

Tags: python, numpy, pde

I am using the finite difference technique, or really just Euler's method but with a partial derivative. There are labeled boundary conditions with the 2 ends in a "water bath". It decays fine for the first 7 time iterations, but on the eighth, the heat signal gets a ton of noise out of nowhere. It must come from the second partial derivative of heat w.r.t. position, but I cannot figure out why.

```
import numpy as np
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Solving the Heat Equation d(u)/d(t) = k * d^2(u)/d(x)^2


tot=100 #just a number of points
L=10 #length of rod
tf=10 #final time
k=3 #k for konstant

x=np.linspace(0,L,tot) #1-D position
t=np.linspace(0,tf,tot) #time
u=np.zeros((tot,tot)) #heat(x,t)

dx=L/tot 
dt=tf/tot


for i in range(tot):
    u[i,0]=6*sin(pi/L*x[i]) #heat at t=0 boundary. Just some function of x



for i in range(tot): #heat at x=0 and x=L edge boundaries
    u[0,i]=0
    u[tot-1,i]=0

for i in range(tot): #i=time
    z=[] #z is just used for plotting
    z.append(u[0,i])
    for j in range(1,tot-1): #j=x-position
        u_xx=(u[j+1,i]-2*u[j,i]+u[j-1,i])/(dx**2) #get u_xx at j,i
        u_t=k*u_xx #solve eq for du/dt
        u[j,i+1]=u_t*dt + u[j,i] #integrate du/dt
        
        z.append(u[j,i])
    z.append(u[tot-1,i])
        
    plt.plot(z)
    plt.show()

    
#print(u[50])#iteration 50
```

Comment: Make `dt` smaller. Instead of `tf/tot`, try, e.g. `dt = 0.001`.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method#Numerical_stability

Answer (score 1):

Numerical schemes may or may not be sustainability. Unstable means that any small error in the solution (e.g., rounding error) increases very quickly.  The scheme you used is unstable. For linear equations, scheme stability analysis can be do with (for example) harmonic analysis. This analysis shows that the Euler scheme will be stable if 2*k*dt/dx/dx<1.
The example of unconditionally stable scheme (Crank–Nicolson scheme) is given below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import time
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def init(x):
    out=np.zeros(len(x))
    out[20:40]=2
    out[60:65]=4
    return out
def bound(t):
    return[np.zeros(t.shape),np.zeros(t.shape)]

def parab_eq(nt,nx,init,bound):
    def tridiag_alg(a,b,c,r):
        #a - first element not used
        #c - end element not used
        #b - main diagonal
        #a - lower diaganal
        #c - upper diaganal
        n=len(b)
        alf=np.zeros(n)
        beta=np.zeros(n)
        out=np.zeros(n)
        alf[0]=-c[0]/b[0]
        beta[0]=r[0]/b[0]
        for ii in range(1,n):
            alf[ii]=-c[ii]/(b[ii]+alf[ii-1]*a[ii])
            beta[ii]=(r[ii]-a[ii]*beta[ii-1])/(b[ii]+alf[ii-1]*a[ii])
        out[-1]=beta[-1]
        for ii in reversed(range(n-1)):
            out[ii]=alf[ii]*out[ii+1]+beta[ii]
        return out
    #nx,nt - number of intervals
    def solve_layer(u,coun_t):
        a=-kdif*dt/dx**2/2.0*np.ones(nx+1)
        b=(1+kdif*dt/dx**2.0)*np.ones(nx+1)
        c=-kdif*dt/dx**2/2.0*np.ones(nx+1)
        r=np.zeros(nx+1)
        for ii in range(1,nx):
            op1=kdif*dt/dx**2/2.0*(u[ii+1,coun_t]-2*u[ii,coun_t]+u[ii-1,coun_t])
            r[ii]=u[ii,coun_t]+op1
        r[1]+=-u[0,coun_t+1]*a[1]
        r[-2]+=-u[-1,coun_t+1]*c[-2]
        return tridiag_alg(a[1:-1],b[1:-1],c[1:-1],r[1:-1])

    t=np.linspace(0,tmax,nt+1)
    x=np.linspace(0,xmax,nx+1)

    dt=tmax/nt; dx=xmax/nx
    u=np.zeros((nx+1,nt+1))
    u[:,0]=init(x)
    u[0,:]=bound(t)[0]
    u[-1,:]=bound(t)[1]

    for count_t in range(nt):
        u[1:-1,count_t+1]=solve_layer(u,count_t)
    return t,x,u

Nx=100
K=2000
kdif=2
tmax=0.1
xmax=2

t,x ,result = parab_eq(K, Nx,init,bound)

f=plt.figure()
ax=plt.axes(xlim=(0,xmax),ylim=(-2,5))

tex = 'Numerical solution for: $\\frac{\\partial^2{u}}{\\partial{t^2}}=k\\frac{\\partial^2{u}}{\\partial{x^2}}$'
plt.title(tex, fontsize=20, color='black')

ax.grid()
plt.ylabel('u')
plt.xlabel('x')
line,=plt.plot([],[],'k')
def init():
    line.set_data([],[])
    return line
def update(frame):
    line.set_data(x,result[:,frame])
    return line

ani = FuncAnimation(f,update, init_func=init,frames=range(0,K,2), interval=100,repeat=True)
plt.show()
```